# Create table syntax for stored procedure's return

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, create-table

I'm wondering if there is a easy way to get a create table syntax for stored procedure's return.

For example we have a stored proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_branches]
AS BEGIN
    select * from branches
END
```

and then I need something like this

```
insert into @tempBranches
exec usp_branches
```

Is there a way that I can easily get create table syntax from stored procedure's return? So for this example I will get this

```
DECLARE @tempBranches TABLE
    (
        BranchID int
        ,BranchName varchar(25)
    )
```

Comment: a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012, yes. There is new functionality that will retrieve metadata based on an ad hoc SQL string or an object name (see https://sqlblog.org/2010/12/20/sql-server-v-next-denali-metadata-enhancements for more details on that).

In earlier versions (you forgot to tell us which version), there are some less reliable workarounds. e.g.

```
SELECT * INTO #table FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 
    'Server=(local);Trusted Connection=Yes;', 
    'EXEC yourdatabase.dbo.usp_branches;');
```

In order to do this you will first need to say:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show adv', 1;
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc dist', 1;
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO
```

Now you can build the `CREATE TABLE` statement based on `tempdb.sys.columns where name LIKE '#table%';`. Or safer `where [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table');`.

Just keep in mind that like the new metadata functionality, if there is more than one resultset (or the shape can change depending on the input), all bets are off.

Comment: @DenisValeev thanks, frankly I think it's a poor solution (there should be better ways to retrieve result metadata), but it sure is a popular workaround. :-)

Comment: I would just go inside the stored procedure and edit the final select to output that into a staging table which could then be scripted to get the metadata. It's especially true for large tables in terms of columns with pretty hard names to spell.

Comment: it is for 2008 but I can try it on server because of security settings.  'SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', see "Surface Area Configuration" in SQL Server Books Online.'

Comment: @DenisValeev well that's not really a "better" solution - meaning one I think the SQL Server team could deliver, not one we would cobble together ourselves.

Comment: @Denis, what is staging table?

Comment: @Cherven a staging table is a table that helps you get things done; a helper table, a temporary table where you're manipulating with data

Comment: @Cherven in sql server you can output resulting data set into another table by using `into` keyword like so: `select * into branches2 from branches`